# Does value type in hadoop type has to implement writable interface?

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, writable

I am trying to understand how to implement custom value type for mapreduce framework. Based on this post ([MapReduce - WritableComparables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12625669/mapreduce-writablecomparables)) it seems to me that the value type has to implement Writable interface. Is that correct?

I was also following the source code various tools (e.g. Import, Export, CopyTable etc.) provided by HBase. Import uses Result as Value type. But Result does not implement Writable interface. How does the serialization step work in this situation?

Answer (score 1):

There are `Writable` and `WritableComparable` in MapReduce.

- `Writable` means MR know how to searialize your object when it have to be sent through wire.
- `WritableComparable` goes one step further, means objects of the class that implement it could be sort.

In MR's implementation, keys would be compared and/or sort during the shuffle procedure, which means it should be `WritableComparable`. values only need to be sent across wire, so `Writable` is enough.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am not sure if I agree with your view that HBase does not deal with MR. In HBase book (published by O'Reilly), they talk about various HBase tools (e.g. CopyTable, Import, Export) that are built on MR. They all implement Tool interface.

Comment: I mean hbase's core functionality was build itself following the Bigtable design, i.e. put, get, the internal memstore etc, no MR job are introduced there. The tools are utilities actually, that could be base on MR.

Comment: Ok. The tools provided by HBase does use MR framework. The value type is Result in general. Result implementation do not implement Writable interface. I am wondering how does the serialization step work here.

Comment: Delete the paragrph on Hbase and would explain later.

Comment: I havent read its code, but think similar serialization step exist. I suppose you could just look at Result implementation and find if similar functionality exist